# MYSQL: Query to Output all related / tags / similar ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a Query, but cant get it do what i want.

I have this table: family

```
family.id
family.name
family.related
```

With this content:

```
id        | name        | related
1         | Name1       | 
2         | Name2       | 3,5
3         | Name3       | 
4         | Name4       | 
5         | Name5       | 4,1
```

As you can see id 2 have related (ids)3,5 but if you go to (id)5 you get another related (ids)4,1

So when i select family.id 2 i want to output: 3,5,4,1

Is this possible with 1 query?

The following query brought me to 3,5 :

```
SELECT

GROUP_CONCAT(related1.related) AS related_ids,

family.id AS id,
family.name AS name,
family.related AS related

FROM family family

LEFT JOIN family related1
              ON FIND_IN_SET(family.id, related1.related) >0

WHERE family.id=5
```

I want to get related_ids to contain 3,5,4,1

Comment: Adding in your case if if 4 is related to lets say 6,7 then we have to display those also?

Comment: yes that would be the case, just dont want to build up / copy the related id's to every row, i hope one id, can seach for its id in other family.related rows, and take their family.related ids as well, and keep building up a new column called related_ids.

Comment: If you know number of level nesting has to be done then you can apply that many joins and get the desired result else it is not possible in single query. Also storing `,` separated values in tables is not a good practice.

Comment: You can get desired result using a stored procedure or a multiple query.

Comment: Please tell me how, im still trying my very best to get something i want... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66306/17/0 it should be possible... the data is there, it just meed to repeat a inner query if there are related ids - just dont know the way to do it right

Comment: I am still at the beginning of building my database, you have any advise to get the related id's better, f.e. in a separated table? and how would the query be to get the ideas from the other table?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of related ids in family.related? You know, this really sucks. It violates first normal form and you should beat up the database designer.

Comment: No, the family.related can be filled up till max VARCHAR(255), is there really no way to do this? ;o

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me out with this problem?